# Whatever I do always get error : Keystore file exists but is empty In Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have browsers with so many threads and postings about "Keystore file exist But is empty", but i can't find a really suitable question and answer match with mine in Unity.

I want to generate a release hash key for login with facebook using facebook sdk 7.9. Since the debug in editor login ran successfully. The problem is when running on the device.

Then I have found a thread that teaches how to show all keystores with an alias.

Below is how to do it :

1. Open CMD
2. Use Command : "keytool -list -keystore "PATH YOUR KEYSTORE"
3. Enter

In this "PATH YOUR KEYSTORE" change with your path ex:

```
c:\unity_project\TTS\mykey
```

But what I get does not always reveal the keystore and the alias. What i get is an error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file exists, 
but is empty: c:\unity_project\TTS\mykey
```

Why do I always got this error?

I have already created a keystore and the keystore is saved in this path:

```
 c:\unity_project\TTS\mykey
```

I have also created a key from the keystore. This can be created with the build setting:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glim2.png
```

Then I have built it without check "Development Build".

So why do I always get the above error? Is it because I need to generate a release hash key for that keystore alias key.

Thanks

Dennis

Comment: Try deleting the  "mykey" directory

Comment: I have try deleting the "mykey" directory and move my tts.keystore to path : c:\unity_project\TTS   But it is not working. Now i got this error :  keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\unity_project\TTS

Comment: Got it.. I go to it directly directory first then call the keystore Name ex : c:\unity_project\TTS>keytool -list -keystore tts.keystore This is working. Thanks @MXD for response to me..:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i got the solution myself.

There is a little mistake I make. add `FileName` at the end of **-keystore** parameter value.

We need to specifiy the keystore file location like this is `path \ tts.keystore` file.
So how to reveal keystore and alias using cmd in my case just type :

`c:\unity_project\TTS>  keytool -list -keystore c:\unity_project\TTS\tts.keystore`